# How to make my iOS app secure work with AWS S3

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I have files on AWS S3 which I want to get by url. I have iOS app which reads this files and everything works fine.

But I want to protect my files so add security and after this I've got a lot of trouble.

So, what I did; I added bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1448129771756",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1448129767926",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::646483417075:role/Cognito_MyAppAuth_Role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my.files.info/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I created Cognito Identity Pool and it generate the code for me:

Then initialize the credentials provider:

```
// Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider  
    
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]
initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
identityPoolId:@"us-east-1:6f261e92-dca3-xxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx"];
          
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
       
[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

But I am writing on Swift so I rewrite this code like:

```
let awsCognitoCredentialsProvider: AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider
let configuration: AWSServiceConfiguration

self.awsCognitoCredentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: AWSRegionType.USEast1,
    identityPoolId: "us-east-1:6f261e92-dca3-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")
            
self.configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider: self.awsCognitoCredentialsProvider)
            AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = self.configuration
```

It works without any errors but I don't see some identities in AWS Cognito Console. I found a lot of code examples but all of them like mine. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made an API call with Cognito? It won't create an id/get credentials unless you do. See the section on getting a Cognito id in the [Cognito docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/getting-credentials/). That'll either create the id or give you an error.

Comment: I tried to call credentialsProvider.getIdentityId but it always returns will (((

Comment: I'm sorry, what is it returning?

Comment: A call to getidentityid or refresh should either create an id or give an error. If it isn't creating an id, can you provide the error you're getting?

Comment: Hmm, it should be giving an error or an id. You're using getIdentityId, not just accessing identityId? If none is set, identityId would give nil. Can you show the code you're using to call that? It'd help narrow it down. Did you try refresh, my other suggestion?

Comment: Thanks man! I fixed my problem. I used to do just self.awsCognitoCredentialsProvider.getIdentityId( when I changed it to var myId = self.awsCognitoCredentialsProvider.getIdentityId() everything fixes.